# Automatically enter command on next line in GNOME Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

Often when I'm deep in a folder structure a have to enter the command far to the right.
I was wondering if there was a setting to always enter the command on the next line.

Similar to this but without the `\` :

```
user@machine:~/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder/folder$ \
> ls
```

Can this somehow be set with an option in GNOME Terminal?
Or should I use another terminal?

Comment: Is `Ctrl+Alt+m` (for bash) or `Alt+Enter` (for zsh)  what you expect?

Comment: What you want is known as a *multiline prompt*. Assuming you use Bash, this can be achieved by including `\n` in the `PS1` variable and is explained [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/).

Comment: Are you sure you want that and don't just want a shorter prompt? For example, if you're in `/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4`, your prompt could simply be `user@machine dir4 $` instead of `user@machine /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4 $`. Would you prefer that?

Comment: This is a question about the _shell_ (e.g. `bash`, `zsh`) and not about the _terminal_. If you wish to configure your system to this extent, I highly recommend that you get familiar with what is a shell vs. what is a terminal.